# error while using occi for writing a udf for oracle db

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to compile a cpp code using the header occi.h the code i am using is 
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    oracle::occi::Environment* environment;
    oracle::occi::Connection *con;
    oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;
    oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;

    try
    {

        environment = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
        con = environment->createConnection("sys", "root","xe");

        stmt = con->createStatement("select * from customers");
        res = stmt->executeQuery();

        while (res->next())
         std::cout<<res->getInt(1)<<"  "<<res->getString(2)<<std::endl;

        stmt->closeResultSet(res);
        con->terminateStatement(stmt);
        environment->terminateConnection(con);

    }catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){
        std::cout<<e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}`
```

i am getting the following errors when i run the following command :-
g++ -I /root/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib:/root/Shared/instantclient_11_2_lib/ -L $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib cpp_db_conn.cpp

error:-
/tmp/ccjcKsxz.o: In function `main':
udf.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to`oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*))'
/tmp/ccjcKsxz.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x80): undefined reference to `typeinfo for oracle::occi::SQLException'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

oracle::occi::Connection|why do you have a space here???|*|and not here???|con;

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you my case.
Obviously, It is a bit-mismatch problem.

My environment is a 'Microsoft SDK v7.0' with 64bit compiler as a default

Unfortunately, my oracle client was a 32-bit, which version is instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0.

I've got the same error with yours.

So, I change my compiler to 32-bit.

```
setenv /x86
```

Then, all problem was gone.

Have a good day.